# g++ does not work for windows (installation after MinGW)

Tags: windows, g++, mingw

I downloaded and installed MinGW to Windows 7 computer. I set Path via My Computer -> Advanced -> ... and added "; C:\MinGW\bin" to the end of the string. But still when I wrote "g++ hello.cpp" to the prompt in the containing folder it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: Just to rule it out, are you using cmd prompt or mingw itself?

Comment: Can you try running cmd.exe it as admin? Any reason your not using mingw/msys shell?

Comment: @jett: Tried what you said but did not work.

Comment: Did you try msys.exe/mingw32 instead of cmd.exe?

Also, when saying "did not work", please elaborate. You are forcing us to guess what doesn't work, an error message along with background information at the minimum is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. When adding path I made it like " ; C:\MinGW\bin". When I remove whitespaces before and after semicolon it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new terminal and try it again.  If that doesn't work, log out and log back in again (I've had to do that in Vista).